# New resource type in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to create a new resource type 'Database' in Android Studio directly under the res folder, but I don't even know where to start.

What I want to do is to define my SQLite database structure and history in XML as a resource file and the result should be a class I can access. When I add a definition in the XML-file for a column I will automatically be able to access that new column in code.

I want it to work in the same way as when I add a string in the strings.xml resource, it's immediately accessible in code.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create a new resource type 'Database' in Android Studio directly under the res folder, but I don't even know where to start.

That is not supported by Android, let alone the development tools.

> I want it to work in the same way as when I add a string in the strings.xml resource, it's immediately accessible in code.

The closest thing to that would be to put your XML in a `res/xml/` directory, which will then give you `R.xml.whatever_you_want_to_call_this_stuff` resource IDs, which you can use with a `Resources` object to read in your XML.

Usually, to package a database with an app, the better solution is to [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) and package the actual SQLite database in `assets/`.

Comment: Thanks four your quick response.

I understand that the resource type 'Database' is not supported by Android Studio, that's why I want to create it. Lets say invent - because i know it does not exists. And I believe there should be some way too hook into the process where the resources are complied and packaged to a resource file.

Comment: @Kakis: "I believe there should be some way too hook into the process where the resources are complied and packaged to a resource file" -- that would require modifying the development tools. Also, the results would not be usable by Android, as the operating system would not know about this resource type. And, you would need to modify relevant framework classes (e.g., `Resources`) to handle this resource type as well. That's all solvable, given lots of time, but then you would need people to run your modded version of Android, and that may prove to be difficult.

Comment: Good comment there. When I read your comment I see that I really don't want a new resource. Just the pattern and tools to generate code. If I design my db with XML I want code generated. And then I can use that code in the same way as if I would have written the code manually. Does that make any sense? I just want to design my database and get all DbClasses generated.